# How to find a good asymptotic approximation of T(n) = T(n/2) + T(n/3) + 1?

Tags: asymptotics

I can't figure out how to find a good asymptotic approximation for the following recurrence relation: $$T(n) = T(n/2) + T(n/3) + 1.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your recurrence as
$$
T(n) = \sum_{i=1}^k a_i T(b_i x + h_i(n))  + g(n)
$$
with:

- $k=2$
- $a_1 = a_2 = 1$
- $b_1 = \frac{1}{2}$, and $b_2 = \frac{1}{3}$
- $h_1(n) = h_2(n) = 0$
- $g(n) = 1$

From [Akra–Bazzi theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method), the solution to your recurrence is $T(n) = \Theta\Big( n^p \big(1 + f(n)\big)\Big)$, where $p$ is such that $a_1 b_1^p + a_2 b_2^p =1$ and $f(n) = \int_1^n \frac{1}{u^{p+1}} \text{d} u$.

Substituting, we have $2^{-p} + 3^{-p} = 1$, which shows that $0.78 < p < 0.79$.

Therefore: $$
f(n) = \int_1^n \frac{1}{u^{p+1}} \text{d} u \le \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{u^{p+1}} \text{d} u = \frac{1}{p} = \Theta(1),
$$

and the solution to your recurrence is $T(n) = \Theta( n^p )$.

Comment: Hi Steven! How did you find p? I calculated as: $-p(\log 2 + log 3) = 1 ==> p = -1/(log 2 + log 3) =-2.30 $

Comment: Careful! $\log(a+b)$ is not $\log(a)+\log(b)$. I don't think there is an easy analytical solution. The function $2^{-p} + 3^{-p}$ is decreasing with $p$ and for $p=0$ it evaluates to $2$ while for $p=1$ it evaluates to $\frac{5}{6}<1 $ so you can approximate it numerically using bisection. Alternatively you can use Newton's method to find the root of $2^{-p} + 3^{-p} -1$ or you can consider the Taylor series centered in $p=0$: $1+\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{(-\ln 2)^i+(-\ln 3)^i}{i!}\cdot x^i$. If you truncate it to polynomials of degrees 3 and 4 you can narrow the range of $p$ to $(0.764, 0.793)$.